# Review of a Azure DevOps pull request

Tags: azure-devops

When reviewing a pull request, is there a way to make all the remarks in one go? And even better would be the ability to also make a draft so I can do the review in stages.

The reason for this is I don't want to interrupt the developer with notification e-mails for each and every comment.